# How to loop over the axes in a subplot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have a loop that generates 15 images. I created a subplot(5,3):

`fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,3)
for i in range(28,43):
      (...).plot(..., ax=axes[?,?])`

I would like that the images appears in sequence: axes[0,0], axes[0,1], axes[0,2], axes[1,0]...

Which argument should I put on axes?

Or is it necessary to create another loop inside the actual?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course you may simply calculate the numbers.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,3)
for i in range(28,43):
      (...).plot(..., ax=axes[(i-28)//3,(i-28)%3])
```

But usually you would rather loop over the axes

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,3)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    (...).plot(..., ax=ax)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, loop over the axes. Thank you.