# Why is i not incrementing in for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I'm new to programming may I know why my `i` is not incrementing in the for loop. I want to update the plot name for each subplot. Thank you.
[image: Code screenshot]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig= plt.figure()
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,squeeze=False)
fig.tight_layout()

i=0
for current_ax in axes:
    current_ax[i].set_title(f"plot: {i}")
    i+=1
```

Comment: [This is how you should loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871318/9245853).

Comment: current_ax is already an Axes instance. you don't need to index it with `i` again, since that is why you are looping. So just: `current_ax.set_title()` should be sufficient

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `current_axes[i]`, just `current_axes`.
Moreover, you could replace your for loop with this:

```
for i, current_ax in enumerate(axes, 0):
    current_ax.set_title(f'Plot: {i}')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because your axes array is like shown below

```
[[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001DCA32BB2E0>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001DCA54476A0>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001DCA547D250>]]
```

so your array have only one plot with three objects in it. while you running your code the loop will only execute once. there is no problem with the counter increment. you can cross check this by printing `i` at the end of loop. so to make work this code in your way first pull out the first element from the array which will make the axes array with 3 objects ie 3 plots.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig= plt.figure()
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,squeeze=False)
fig.tight_layout()
i=0
print('figarray1',axes)
axes=axes[0]
print('figarray2',axes)
for current_ax in axes:
    current_ax.set_title(f"plot: {i}")
    i+=1
    print(i)
plt.show()
```

**output graph**

[image]

**Terminal Output**

```
figarray1 [[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEB72B2E0>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEF9266A0>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEF95D250>]]
figarray2 [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEB72B2E0>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEF9266A0>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000020AEF95D250>]
1
2
3
```

Comment: This explanation was fantastic. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @LordVoldemort This is the correct answer, I recommend that you approve it (click the check mark on the left of the answer body) — I'd like to add that your problem arises from the keyword argument `squeeze=False`, if you try your code WITHOUT  `squeeze=False` the loop as you have written it is perfectly fine.  Play a little with different number of rows and columns in `subplots(…)` with or without the `squeeze=False` and you'll see what I mean…

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `enumerate` here, as it is considered more Pythonic than indexing.

#### Below is how you would set both the **titles** and **axes**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, squeeze=False)
fig.tight_layout()

# enumerate titles for each plot (blue boxes in output below)   
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.set_title(f'Title {i}')

# label x and y axis for each plot (red boxes in output below)
plt.setp(axes, xlabel='x axis label')
plt.setp(axes, ylabel='y axis label')
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]