# How to plot a dictionary of dataframes to subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dict including different series. Each series has a different length and I am going to have plots of bar chart for them, each in a subplot. Here is the dict:

```
data = {'df_A': 0         0
 1         0
 2         0
 3         0
 4         0
 5     14343
 6     14343
 7         0
 8      8107
 9        11
 10        0
 11     2276
 12        0
 dtype: int64,
 'df_B': 0       0
 1       0
 2       0
 3    6692
 dtype: int64,
 'df_C': 0    323059
 1         0
 2         0
 3         0
 dtype: int64}
```

To have the plot, I run the following code, but I get the error:
**'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'bar'**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 1)

for i,key in enumerate(data):

     ax.bar(range(len(data[key])),list(data[key]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the observation of @BigBen, and using [Dataframe.plot.bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'df_A': pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14343, 14343, 0, 8107, 11, 0, 2276,0]),
        'df_B': pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 6692]),
        'df_C': pd.DataFrame([323059, 0, 0, 0])}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 1)

for i, key in enumerate(data):

     data[key].plot.bar(ax=axes[i]) # Tell the DataFrame which axis to add the plot to

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

- See [How to loop over the axes in a subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51868628/7758804) to loop through, and plot to an `axes`.
- The OP shows a dictionary of DataFrames
- Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the dataframes in the dictionary into a single dataframe, and then plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  - I recommend setting `sharey=True` (`False` by default), to show all the bars on the same scale.
- This is a simpler implementation, which removes the need to iterate through a dictionary, and `axes`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'df_A': pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14343, 14343, 0, 8107, 11, 0, 2276,0]),
        'df_B': pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 6692]),
        'df_C': pd.DataFrame([323059, 0, 0, 0])}

# combine the dataframes
df = pd.concat(data.values(), axis=1)

# set the column names
df.columns = data.keys()

# plot the dataframe
df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, figsize=(6, 6), legend=False)

# rotate the ticks
plt.xticks(rotation=0)

# add separation between the figures
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]